# How do you turn off Mingw / Git Bash "ctrl left click" open Hyperlink Feature?

Tags: windows, bash, git, mingw

When Mingw / Git bash is open and you hold down ctrl, it begins underlining words. If you click them (or seemingly just hover over them) the operating system then attempts to open the word as a file or network link.

Is there anyway to turn off this "feature"?

I am navigating around in Vim holding ctrl and the editor constantly opens error windows "The network path was not found. \name" (With a hilariously bad button that changes randomly from "Ok" to "I see" to "Cancel" depending on the alignment of the moons).

Note this is on Windows 10.

Comment: It's not a bash thing, it'd be a terminal thing, and it doesn't look like it's an option for MingW. Which means you have to use something else, same bash shell, different wrapper. I'd suggest [conemu](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu) or (if you want a lazy preconfig'd implementation) [cmder](https://cmder.net/).

Comment: Also note, if you're holding down buttons in Vim excessively, it's a sign you could probably be doing something different.

Comment: @marblewraith, what is strange is I don't remember this happening for the last few weeks using this setup.
I'm not sure about whether its a sign of something... I'm actually seeing it excessively error just by doing nearly any work. Ctrl is used all the time for page up and page down or navigating within the view screen. (This is where i'm getting hit left right and center with errors).

Comment: I'll take a look at these and see if its feasible. I am currently using the ssh feature in git/bash and working code on a remote system.

Comment: Then the key is to remember what you've updated and try rolling back. For example if you're using a VIM plugin manager, that could be a source of trouble if it auto-updates. Or perhaps if you use a package manager such as chocolatey to install git/bash then updates from there might have broken something.